# Better way to select Monthly or Yearly with custom option

Tags: dates

I need to give an option for Monthly / Yearly filter with Customized one.

- They can choose any month (this month, previous month.... month from any previous year)
- They can choose any year

I have come up with few options, please give me your feedback on this. Which one is more usable to select month / year with custom option?

NOTE: The right side calendar component for customized Monthly / Yearly options.

---

[image]

Comment: If you give the user the possibility to zoom/unzoom after selecting monthly or yearly. Maybe choosing the right interface will be easier as wrong selection in first choice is not irreversible.

Comment: Yes, you are correct but we can solve this problem in Visual aspect. Correct?

Comment: It all looks very mouse-heavy with lots of clicks needed to change views, select items and switch to different controls. Can you not combine it into one single control, or offer a text entry option and just convert whatever they type into an actual date?

Comment: Also, I don't really understand what you mean by a 'custom one'. Wouldn't just saying 'I need a month / year filter' be accurate? 'A month year filter with a custom option' is confusing as I don't know what you mean by the custom part.

Comment: @JonW, thanks for your comments. Custom option meaning for he can choose any month from different year. That's why I have shown 'Calendar' icon for custom value.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing a simple 2 steps process ?
It's a 2 click for every options.

[image]